# Will Denial of Entry in transit at YVR affect my new US visa request?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, denial-of-entry

I'm Indian citizen and was traveling back from Seattle, US to New Delhi, India via 2 layovers Vancouver & Frankfurt. Though I went to Seattle via single layover at Frankfurt. I had single entry B1 Visa (90 days) which allowed me to attend a technical conference.
While coming back, I was stopped at Vancouver as I lacked Transit visa. I was under wrong impression that they will let me transit if I have US Visa. :(

Immigration officer inquired for some time and told me that they sending me back to Seattle, where I came from. They asked me to sign document with following text:
pursuant to paragraph 42(1) of the immigration and refugee protection regulations, I am allowing you to withdraw your application to enter canada and to leave canada without delay

Followed by my sign on following text:
I hereby voluntarily withdraw my application to enter Canada and agree to leave Canada without any delay.

My passport was stamped (immigration stamp) by US Immigration officer to enter back to US (on my single entry visa). No remarks were written on passport, though US Immigration officer wrote some stuff on his computer screen.  All this happened Oct 2012.

Now, I wish to reapply for US Visa this Oct (2013). I'm concerned if this event will have any impact on new VISA request.

Comment: Similar: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109183/denied-entry-to-canada-will-this-history-deny-me-entry-to-other-countries?rq=1

Answer (score 10):

As far as I'm aware, the US visa application process only asks whether you have ever been denied entry *to the US*, not to any other countries.  Since you were refused entry to Canada, not the United States, what happened *should* thus not have any impact on any future US visa applications.

But needless to say, if you ever find yourself needing a Canadian visa, you will definitely have to state that you have been denied entry and explain why.  And if the US *does* ever ask what happened, or whether you've been denied entry elsewhere, you should also explain the truth.

Comment: Even then; I don't think he was refused entry; if you read OPs post he mentions that he was given a form that states he "Withdraws" his application to enter Canada; a Withdrawl is completly different to a refusal and you don't have to declare a withdrawl in the same way you would a refusal. see https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109183/denied-entry-to-canada-will-this-history-deny-me-entry-to-other-countries?rq=1