# Should I mention my Canadian visa refusal in my UK visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, canada, visa-refusals

My Canada visa was refused; I got a refusal letter but nothing was stamped in my passport. I got rejected under section 205(a) and 186 for not demonstrating specialized knowledge.

Do I have to mention the Canadian refusal in my UK work permit visa application? Will it affect my application (it is not an offense or criminal case)?

Comment: @Galaxy No, completely unrelated?  That one is about previous rejections *to the UK* (and the answer talks about biometric data, which Canada may or may not share with UK), this is about previous rejections to a completely different country?

Comment: As a work permit (i.e long stay visa) question, should this be directed to expatriates.se?

Comment: What does it say on the form? Have you read the exact questions it asks?

Comment: @Yakk, granted, misunderstood the question. Have removed the tag.

Answer (score 20):

Yes you should mention it (because they **do** ask you that).  A possible refusal is better than a ban for deception.

A previous refusal from another country, or even the same one, does not mean that your application will necessarily be refused.

Here is the exact text of the questions as of **November 2018**.

> **Have you ever been:**
>
> - refused a visa for the UK
> - deported from the UK
> - removed from the UK
> - required to leave the UK
> - refused entry at the UK border
>
> **Have you ever been:**
>
> - refused a visa for any country other than the UK
> - deported from any country other than the UK
> - removed from any country other than the UK
> - required to leave any country other than the UK
> - refused entry at the border of any country other than the UK

If the answer to either of those questions is yes, then you get a section to provide details. If the answer is No, then the wizard moves forward.

The form is not available for download online so i don't have a  reference to link to but this can be verified at https://visas-immigration.service.gov.uk

Comment: Are you asserting that the UK requires you to mention visa refusals *in other countries*?  Are you asserting they even ask?  Or are you saying the OP should volunteer that information, unasked for and unrequired?

Comment: @Yakk they **do** ask both of those questions separately, and the only correct answer is **Yes** if you've had a refusal. Any answer here comes with the implied context that it's primarily answering the question that was asked, and not writing  general theory. The question was for the UK and they do ask. There is no mention of volunteering any information in this answer.

Answer (score 10):

The form explictly asks if you have ever been refused a visa by any country. You must answer all questions on your visa application truthfully and accurately. If you are found to have lied, this is taken very seriously and will usually mean that you're banned from getting a visa for a number of years or even forever.

Comment: This appears to be a non-answer to the OP's question, unless you are claimiing "and the UK visa application requests you list all non-UK visas you have been refused" or something similar.  I mean, "the UK visa application requires you to use number 2 pencil" may also be true (I doubt it), but unless connected to the OP's question, it seems a strange thing to mention.  If this is related to the OP's question, can you please state that explicitly?

Comment: @Yakk It completely answers the question. I don't know what the UK application form asks, but it doesn't matter. If the form asks any question where the truthful answer is "I had an application for a Canadian visa rejected on date X for reason Y", then the asker must state that. If it doesn't ask any question where that is the truthful answer, then they don't have to state that.

Comment: @Yakk I'm assuming the question is "How do I fill in the form?" rather than "Does the form ask about this?" I agree that, if the question is supposed to be the latter, then I've not answered it.

Comment: @Yakk, Given that it's a UK visa, it's fairly likely it'll have a question along the lines of "Have you been refused a visa for any country, including the UK, in the last 10 years".

Comment: We're all guessing here. @vana, please quote *the exact words* of the question(s) you're asking about.

Comment: @David the exact question in application is "refused a visa for any country other than the UK?" , if i say yes for the question will it affect my chance of getting approved? ........... The reason for Canada refusal mentioned was " You have not demonstrated specialized knowledge and your employer must obtain LMIA number"

Comment: @vana You must answer all questions on your visa application truthfully, giving full details.

Comment: @David I'm sorry but it is categorically not a guess that the form must be filled in truthfully and completely. Speak for yourself, but I'm not guessing anything.

Comment: An example of the Tier2 visa application form here  https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/752361/vaf-2-11-18.pdf Section 7.3 requires the applicant to confirm that they have included information on problems with immigration for either the UK or any other country. Specifically: Refused a visa; Refused entry at the border; Refused permission to stay/remain; Deported; Removed; Required to leave; Excluded/Banned from entry. I have not seen the online version but it would be reasonable to assume it is the same.

Answer (score 6):

There is no requirement to disclose information you have not been asked for, unless and until you are asked. Therefore, if the visa application you are filing requests further information about entry to other countries, Commonwealth countries, or Canada in particular, then you should disclose the information you have been asked to provide. If it includes visa applications and their approval or refusal, outside the UK, then you would need to disclose your refusal by the Canadian authorities.

Preparing for an interview, however, should involve documenting any point of potential uncertainty for the consular officer, and being prepared to answer any questions, ideally with something in writing to back it up. If there are or were mitigating circumstances that explain or justify your position in relation to the refusal, then you should prepare yourself to answer questions with that information, and take with you any supporting evidence. This often requires thinking outside the box and is not as straightforward as an application form.

My answer comes from having both successfully applied for my own visas and assisted others in filing applications and preparing for interviews, including in/for the UK, and for both immigrant and non-immigrant classes.

Comment: I've also come across this nugget that suggests the UK has access to Canadian refusals, so you should definitely answer truthfully if asked **and** prepare well for any interview, whether at the embassy or the port of entry, and probably both: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/109183/denied-entry-to-canada-will-this-history-deny-me-entry-to-other-countries/125610#125610