# Will the UK home office know about 5 previous visa rejections in other countries?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, student-visas

I have been rejected for visas 5 times in 4 countries. 3 of those were Schengen countries. Now, I want to study in the UK. Will it be a big issue?. Will the UK home office know everything about my rejection?

Comment: They actually ask if you were rejected by any country. The chances of them finding out are low but if they do and you have lied, you’ll be banned from the UK.

Comment: (The OP's second question "Will the UK know?" is answered in this previous question.I disagree with @greatone's comment above; I think the liklihood of the UK knowing is very high.) Possible duplicate of [Is changing your passport a good strategy for removing a negative immigration history in Schengen?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67808/is-changing-your-passport-a-good-strategy-for-removing-a-negative-immigration-hi)

Comment: What stamps are in your passport? The UK shares immigration data with certain countries including the US and Canada. They may not know ‘everything’ about your visa rejection history (unless it was the UK) but if the application form asks (and it very probably does) you must tell the truth. If you lie and they find out, you’ll be banned for deception. Study visa eligibility requirements are not the same as those for a visitor, so it’s not a given that your history will cause a problem. It depends eg on the reason(s) for the refusals, which you’ve not stated in your question.

Comment: i got refused 4 years back. now i have changed my passport but in my new passport the old passport number is there

Comment: @David the UK does not have any formal automated visa refusal sharing with any Schengen country. They do NOT have access to the immigration information is the SIS II or VIS (while they have access to some other information). In theory, they can always ask on a case-by-case basis, but unless they have suspicion, there is no way they will be checking up on a study visa. If you have doubts, a FOI request will clear up what and how the Home Office has access to.

Comment: @greatone I agree (as far as public info w/o an FOI requests can demonstrate) that you're right that the UK doesn't automatically get Schengen immigration info directly. OTOH, the reality isn't at the other end of the continuum either - it's not demonstrable that the UK doesn't get the or some information elsewhere (as from the SISII criminal database, or other sources). Given the serious consequences of "getting it wrong," I think travelers should _not_ assume that the UK _doesn't_ have any EU information on them. And surely: one's risk tolerance may vary.

Comment: Unless your situation has changed significantly, it's more likely that you will be rejected not because of previous rejections but for the same reasons those 4 countries rejected you previously.

Answer (score 15):

The application form asks:

> #### Immigration history
>
> For either the UK or any other country, have you ever been:
>
> - Refused a visa
> - Refused entry at the border
> - Refused permission to stay or remain
> - Refused asylum
> - Deported
> - Removed
> - Required to leave
> - Excluded or banned from entry

It then asks for further details (what happened, what country, when, and free text details). It will ask for it for as many events as necessary.

So, as you will not lie about it, they will know.

If you think about lying about it, **don't**. There are good chances they will find out, and if they do, you'll be in a lot of trouble, and will not only be refused a visa, but will most probably be banned for many many years.

Having been refused so many times is definitely not in your favour, though we don't know the details about those rejections, when they happened, why they happened, and if your circumstances may have changed since then. Even if the reason for your visa request has changed, you should most definitely make sure you address all the issues they raised before applying for a UK visa.

Answer (score 5):

Given the information contained in [this answer in this SE:Travel question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/67808/is-changing-your-passport-a-good-strategy-for-removing-a-negative-immigration-hi), I think the UK is extremely likely to know about your Schengen refusals.

You haven't named the non-Schengen refusal countries, so no one can answer as to them.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this SE:Travel answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/125586/should-i-mention-my-canadian-visa-refusal-in-my-uk-visa-application), you are required to provide such information. If not provided you will almost certainly be refused for deception.

As it is, your case isn't strong. 1 visa rejection isn't good, 5 is awful. You should be completely honest in explaining the refusals and the reasons for them. Schengen and UK do exchange information so most likely the home office will know.